# Slow typing on go mode

Tags: spacemacs, golang

need a little help here, my emacs is so slow if while writing go code, it look like it is stuttering.

On my observation, it happens because I have "not that" a lot folders in my src directory, most of them is just source of the installed packages and a few sample projects that I clone.

Then when I remove all the packages and just keep one sample project, It runs so smooth.

Please help how I can resolve this, thanks.

P.S. I am using spacemacs config